# не компилируется файл port.cpp

Tags: c++

Вопрос такой пишу собственную ОС в файле port.cpp компилятор G++ ругается не компилит вываливает кучу ошибок да и сам Visual Studio Code нашёл 9 ошибок что делать не знаю выкладываю файл port.cpp и port.h сам я работаю в Ubuntu 16.04 x64

port.cpp

```
#include "port.h"

Port::Port(uint16_t portnumber)
{
    this->portnumber = portnumber;
}

Port::~Port()
{
}

Port8Bit::Port8Bit(uint8_t portnumber)
: Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port8Bit::~Port8Bit()
{
}

void Port8Bit::Write(uint8_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile("outb %0, %1" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber);
}

uint8_t Port8Bit::Read()
{
    uint8_t result;
    __asm__ volatile("inb %1, %0" : : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (portnumber);
    return result;
}

Port8BitSlow::Port8BitSlow(uint8_t portnumber)
        : Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port8BitSlow::~Port8BitSlow()
{
}

void Port8BitSlow::Write(uint8_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile("outb %0, %1\njmp 1f\n1: jmp 1f\n1:" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber);
}

Port16Bit::Port16Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
: Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port16Bit::~Port16Bit()
{
}

void Port16Bit::Write(uint16_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile("outw %0, %1" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber);
}

uint16_t Port16Bit::Read()
{
    uint16_t result;
    __asm__ volatile("inw %1, %0" : : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (portnumber);
    return result;
}

Port32Bit::Port32Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
: Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port32Bit::~Port32Bit()
{
}

void Port32BitWrite(uint32_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile("outl %0, %1" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber)));
}

uint32_t Port16BitRead()
{
    uint32_t result;
    __asm__ volatile("inl %1, %0" : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (portnumber)));
    return result;
}
```

port.h

```
#ifndef __PORT_H
#define __PORT_H


#include "types.h"


    class Port
    {
    protected:
        uint16_t portnumber;
        Port(uint16_t portnumber);
        ~Port();
    };

    class Port8Bit : public Port
    {
    public:
        Port8Bit(uint16_t portnumber);
        ~Port8Bit();
        virtual void Write(uint8_t data);
        virtual uint8_t Read();
    };

    class Port8BitSlow : public Port8Bit
    {
    public:
        Port8BitSlow(uint16_t portnumber);
        ~Port8BitSlow();
        virtual void Write(uint8_t data);
    };

    class Port16Bit : public Port
    {
    public:
        Port16Bit(uint16_t portnumber);
        ~Port16Bit();
        virtual void Write(uint16_t data);
        virtual uint16_t Read();
    };

    class Port32Bit : public Port
    {
    public:
        Port32Bit(uint16_t portnumber);
        ~Port32Bit();
        virtual void Write(uint32_t data);
        virtual uint32_t Read();
    };


#endif
```

ошибки из теримнала

```
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS5$ make clean
rm -f loader.o gdt.o port.o kernel.o mykernel.bin mykernel.iso
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS5$ make run
as --32 -o loader.o loader.s
g++ -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -o gdt.o -c gdt.cpp
g++ -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -o port.o -c port.cpp
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Port8Bit::Write(uint8_t)’:
port.cpp:27:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
     __asm__volatile("outb %0, %1" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber);
                                   ^
port.cpp:27:67: error: expression cannot be used as a function
     __asm__volatile("outb %0, %1" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber);
                                                                   ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint8_t Port8Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:33:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
     __asm__volatile("inb %1, %0" : : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (portnumber);
                                  ^
port.cpp: In constructor ‘Port8BitSlow::Port8BitSlow(uint16_t)’:
port.cpp:40:3: error: type ‘Port’ is not a direct base of ‘Port8BitSlow’
 : Port(portnumber)
   ^
port.cpp:40:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘Port8Bit::Port8Bit()’
 : Port(portnumber)
                  ^
port.cpp:16:1: note: candidate: Port8Bit::Port8Bit(uint16_t)
 Port8Bit::Port8Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
 ^
port.cpp:16:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from port.cpp:2:0:
port.h:17:11: note: candidate: Port8Bit::Port8Bit(const Port8Bit&)
     class Port8Bit : public Port
           ^
port.h:17:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Port8BitSlow::Write(uint8_t)’:
port.cpp:50:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
     __asm__volatile("outb %0, %1\njmp 1f\n1: jmp 1f\n1:" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (
                                                          ^
port.cpp:50:90: error: expression cannot be used as a function
 olatile("outb %0, %1\njmp 1f\n1: jmp 1f\n1:" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber);
                                                                              ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Port16Bit::Write(uint16_t)’:
port.cpp:68:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
     __asm__volatile("outw %0, %1" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber);
                                   ^
port.cpp:68:67: error: expression cannot be used as a function
     __asm__volatile("outw %0, %1" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber);
                                                                   ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint16_t Port16Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:74:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
     __asm__volatile("inw %1, %0" : : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (portnumber);
                                  ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Port32Bit::Write(uint32_t)’:
port.cpp:94:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
     __asm__volatile("outl %0, %1" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber)));
                                   ^
port.cpp:94:67: error: expression cannot be used as a function
     __asm__volatile("outl %0, %1" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber)));
                                                                   ^
port.cpp:94:68: error: ‘__asm__volatile’ was not declared in this scope
     __asm__volatile("outl %0, %1" : : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber)));
                                                                    ^
port.cpp: At global scope:
port.cpp:97:10: error: prototype for ‘uint32_t Port16Bit::Read()’ does not match any in class ‘Port16Bit’
 uint32_t Port16Bit::Read()
          ^
port.cpp:71:10: error: candidate is: virtual uint16_t Port16Bit::Read()
 uint16_t Port16Bit::Read()
          ^
Makefile:9: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «port.o»
make: *** [port.o] Ошибка 1
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS5$
```

Comment: А теперь, я так понимаю, мы должны угадать что за ошибки?

Comment: Я могу выложить ошибки из терминала

Comment: *что делать не знаю* - как что, читать сообщения об ошибках, которые пишет компилятор. Там обычно прямым текстом написано, что не так с вашим кодом.

Comment: добавил сообщение об ошибках

Comment: Ассемблерная вставка неправильно написана. Не хватает закрывающей скобки, плюс, выходные параметры и входные надо писать на разных строчках. А вы всё в одну записали.

Comment: а можно как то показать пример того как должно быть а то я начинающий прогер

Answer (score 2):

Ассемблерная вставка написана неправильно - не хватает закрывающей скобки.

И лучше не экономить на строчках, а писать нормально:

```
void Port8Bit::Write(uint8_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile (
        "outb %0, %1" 
        : 
        : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber)
    );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое